How do I add a radius to tkinter.Button using python?
I have questions and problems.
I want a round edge or radius for buttons in Python with the Tkinter graphic user interface modal.
If possible, tell me what the methods are for this.
Button(radius = 50)


Try CTkButton from CustomTkinter module.

Does this answer your question? How to make a rounded button tkinter?

It's hard to give a radius to button or other widgets in tkinter. It's possible, but hard. It's easier to use customtkinter library.
step 1:
open terminal and write down:
py -m pip install customtkinter.
step 2:
use this library to have a rounded button.
like this:
from tkinter import *
import customtkinter

root = Tk()
btn1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(
    root,
    text='Click me!',
    border_color='green',
    border_width=3,
    border_spacing=10,
    corner_radius=50,
    )
btn1.grid(row=1, column=1)

mainloop()

This is a simple code to test. For more samples, visit their github.
Visit documentation for detailed information.

tank you for your Answers
